# How to configure Rails to use different version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 3.0.1 application which works with Ruby 1.9.2.

However, I noticed that Rails 1.8.7 is installed on the server.

What steps should I take to install Ruby 1.9.2 on the server, and force my application to use it ?

I use Apache and Passenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend installing [RVM](https://rvm.io) and using that to set the version of Ruby that you want on the server.

Here's a rundown of its advantages in a production environment:

> RVM allows users to deploy each
>   project with its own completely
>   self-contained and dedicated
>   environment--from the specific version
>   of ruby all the way down to the
>   precise set of required gems to run
>   the application. Having a precise set
>   of gems also avoids the issue of
>   version conflicts between projects,
>   causing difficult-to-trace errors and
>   hours of hair loss. With RVM, NO OTHER
>   GEMS than those required are
>   installed. This makes working with
>   multiple complex applications where
>   each has a long list of gem
>   dependencies efficient. RVM allows us
>   to easily test gem upgrades by
>   switching to a new clean set of gems
>   to test with while leaving our
>   original set intact. It is flexible
>   enough to even have a set of gems per
>   environment or development branch--or
>   even individual developer's taste!

It's very easy to setup and use, especially compared to managing the Ruby versions yourself. I've done both and I prefer RVM much more now. Once you have RVM installed, using Ruby 1.9.2 is as easy as:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm use 1.9.2
```

And then you can check which version of Ruby your production environment is using with:

```
ruby -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Apache, reinstall Passenger with

```
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
```

while having Ruby 1.9.2 active. If you use [RVM](https://rvm.io) just type `rvm use 1.9.`2 to make that version of Ruby active. Follow the on-screen instructions for how to modify your httpd.conf.